# Inserting Data into a Column within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to Populate the username field/column with the first letter of the `survey_responder`s firstname concatenated with the last name of the survey responder.

Every time I run my code it gives me an error :

> You can't specify target table 'survey_responders' for update in FROM clause"

Any help with what I'm doing wrong anyone?

```
update survey_responders 
    set username = ((select CONCAT(left(first_name,1), last_name) 
        from survey_responders)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I would really like to understand what I did wrong so I don' make the same mistake again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Moses Mc, you can write comments to answers right on the bottom of every answers. If you have a spare time feel free to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE survey_responders SET username = CONCAT(LEFT(first_name,1), last_name);
```

You don't need to do the SELECT query that you did. In UPDATE command, in every row you can use  all the columns that you have.